# Codeigniter: AJAX request don't have response data

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, request

I have a simple app in codeigniter. In my view I have ajax POST request to the controller, but I don't receive response data. I checked in the chrome dev tool in network tab the response and the message is: No response data available for this request :
My view:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>

<td>First</td>
<td>Sec</td>
<td>Th</td>
<td>Th</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
if(isset($result))
{
foreach($result as $value)
{
    echo "<tr><td>". $value->cai . "</td><td>". $value->partner ."</td><td>". $value->spot ."</td><td><button type='button' id='".$value->cai."' class='btn btn-danger delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
 
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php echo $this->pagination_bootstrap->render(); ?>
<script>
$('.table').on('click','.delete',function(){
    
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var confirm_box=confirm('Sure?');
    if(confirm_box === true)
    {
        $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('Tires_Crud/deleteCai'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            key: id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        }
    });
    
    }
});
</script>
```

My controller:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tires_Crud extends MY_Controller
{

  
    

    public function deleteCai()
    {

        $status = array(
            "STATUS" => "true"
        );
        return  json_encode($status);
        }

}
```

In my config file  CSRF protection is DISABLED! Because  when its enabled the ajax request is not working. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: so your question is actually about *How to get response data with CSRF set to true, like `$config['csrf_protection'] = true;`?* please confirm

Comment: No. With CSRF protection enabled the ajax request is not working. I got a message: Not allowed

Comment: I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

Some issues with this code.

#1: The way you're forming the ajax request. Where you have `type: 'POST'` should be `method: 'POST'` - but more than a typo, it's important that you understand these are referred to as the HTTP **method** - same way you'd specify that in a `<form method='post'` tag. If you don't provide a `method`, it's assumed to be `GET`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Also, because you specified `dataType:'json'` - jquery will deliver a ready to use parsed JSON object. No need for you to parse it yourself

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo site_url('Tires_Crud/deleteCai'); ?>',
  method: 'POST', // <-- change this from 'type' to 'method'
  data: {
        key: id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log(JSON.parse(data)); // <-- no need to parse - you have set dataType to be json, which means it will come to you already parsed
        console.log(data);
    })
```

#2 - In your PHP, you'd catch your `key` variable (you sent in ajax) with `$_POST['key']` - though in codeigniter you get it like this:

```
// codeigniter 2.x and 3.x
$this->input->post('key');  

// codeigniter 4
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;
$request = service('request');
$request->getPost('key');
```

#3 - With ajax, you actually `echo` the response, rather than `return` it:

```
public function deleteCai(){
  $status = array(
    "STATUS" => "true"
  );
  echo  json_encode($status);
}
```

Comment: @devax19 - did this help?

Comment: @devax19 Thank you for your reply, but I  still don't receive a response message.

Comment: and you're sure your POST request is getting sent (you see in your network tab that its in the reqeust header) - and you're sure the url field is resolving correctly in your ajax request (`site_url(...)`)? Turn PHP error reporting on (right before sending the ajax request) to see if it's causing an error.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: also what version of CI?

Comment: Yes im sure. The response code is 200  in network tabs

Comment: version is 2.2.0

Comment: There is nothing in the console If i put  console.log('something'); in the success area, i don't know why..